# How to migrate Universal Analytics conversions to Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

I have added the Measurement ID and added the scripts to **<head/** & **<body/** tags as well, I am also able to see the real time data such as scroll, page-view events.

But when I go the Google Analytics 4 **Admin** --> **select GA4 Property** --> **Setup Assistant** --> **Property Settings** --> **Set up conversions** --> **Import from Universal Analytics** --> **Select all the conversions** --> **Import selected conversions**.

Then I am getting a popup saying

**"Google Analytics 4 (GA4) not receiving events from Universal Analytics(UA)"**

Can anyone help me with the correct process to get the conversions imported to GA4. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to check while migrating to GA4.

1. Add custom dimension values from universal analytics to Google Analytics 4.
2. Check whether the data is passing in 'Debug view' under the property tab in Admin